# google map client side geocoding "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using client side reverse geocoding to get the address on the basis of latitude and longitude.

I have read google documentation and it says that client side geocoding allows 2500 geocoding request per client ip.

In order to test this i made more than 2500 client side geocoding request on my local machine and as expected google gave me "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" issue.

But the problem is that if i hit the same client side reverse geocoding request on another machine located at same network then also it is giving me "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" issue.

I don't know why it is giving me "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" issue if the client side geocoding is per client ip address ??

Thanks,
Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: the title is not very descriptive. "Issue" could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is per outside (Internet) facing IP adress. Both of the machines are probably accessing the service you are using via the same internet connection thus from googles perspective its the same IP.

Even though both machines will have different IPs in your network.

Regarding your question about the qouta reset after 24 hours.

From the [google maps api usage limit documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) :

> The time of day at which the daily quota for a service is reset varies
>   between customers and for each API, and can change over time.

Comment: Are you sure that it is per outside (internet) facing ip address because it is not documented anywhere.  Also i am still facing this issue even after the next day. google document says that it provides new quota per day. Then why i am getting this quota limit on very next day ???